# Query in MongoDB (Pymongo) with operator $in using with ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of ID's and I want to query a collection based on that list. The field I'm filtering is `id_`, it is an `ObjectID`.

Example:

`list = ['abcd','mnop','qrst']`

I want to search documents that the `_id` is in that list:

```
cursor = db.find( {"_id": { "$in": list} }   )
cursor = db.find( {"_id": { "$in": ObjectId(list)} }   )
```

I tried both options above and none of them worked.
The first one returned empty, and the second one throws a type error:
`TypeError: id must be an instance of (bytes, str, ObjectId), not <class 'list'>`

How can I correct my code?

Comment: Have you tried something like this for a list of `ObjectId`s: `[ ObjectId('61bde475a216f8027c1379d1'), ...]`

Comment: It Works. `list = [ObjectId(x) for x in list]`. Thanks. Feel free to awnser the question

Answer (score 1):

As @prasad_ said, it is needed to generate the ObjectId from the string.

```
list_ = ['abcd','mnop','qrst']
list_ = [ObjectId(x) for x in list_]
cursor = db.find( {"_id": { "$in": list_} } )
```

So the `"$in"` operator of MongoDB refers to the list that has ObjectId's as its content.